# Missing photos on a roll of film?

Tags: film, fujifilm, 35mm, developing

So I have a Fujifilm Big Viewfinder 50AF, the counter on the top said I had taken 24 pictures (the whole roll) but when I got the film developed today there were only 14 photos??? and the 10 photos that are missing are from the middle of the roll. Is there something wrong with my camera or was it the developers fault. The missing pictures weren't even on the negatives, I'm so confused.

Comment: The film *should* have numbers on it indicating film.  Are they consecutive? is there a missing range? (the frame numbers are along the sprockets: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pazap.jpg )

Comment: Is there any chance of them being not recoverable? (e.g. burned, black...)

Comment: They seem to be consecutive. there isn't a missing range, all the numbers go in order up to 14 and then after that is blank, but the pictures missing were not from the end of the roll.

Comment: Does any of the images look double exposed? Is sounds like the camera did all the 24 exposures, but didn't feed the film for the 10 missing photos.

Comment: none of the pictures look double exposed. how would I go about fixing this problem?

Answer (score 6):

If you are sure you took 10 photos in the middle of the roll and they don't appear, it sounds like there is a mechanical problem that prevented the film advancing *and* prevented the shutter opening for 10 exposures, which somehow then righted itself after those exposures.

There is a slight chance it could be due to not fully winding the film on during that time (maybe you didn't reach a "final click") but I'd otherwise be blaming the camera.

It's interesting that you stopped taking pictures when the indicator reached 24 rather than when the film will no longer wind.  It's generally fine to get a few more exposures on any remaining length of film at the end if you can - once the film truly runs out you'll notice it stop winding on and the camera should refuse to take more photos.  You may be able to get up to 27 exposures from a roll of 24 this way.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that images missing from the middle point directly to either a mechanical issue, or some other factor where the lens was blocked. A severe under-exposure could also be the culprit.

In regards to your question about this possibly being an issue caused by your film processing vendor:
If the film itself shows edge print - the text on the edges of the sprockets - all the way through the roll, then your issue is certainly NOT a problem with the developer. The edge type is exposed onto the film by the manufacturer in the way that your images are exposed on the film. That text will only show up if the film is developed.  So edge print is there and the frames are blank, then you can safely deduce the film was not exposed in those areas by your camera.

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago I had a missing negative but a print produced!  They lost it after they printed.  But other funny details pointed to a cover up, piecing together end from a different roll.

I asked online (Compuserve if anyone remembers that) and was told that photo places often messed up and hide it blaming the customer.  That included posts from pros who worked in chain photo stores when younger, so I took it on authority.  Also had told me what to look for and what to tell the manager at Ritz to get out of brush-off mode.

My point is that processing vendors might reasonably be to blame for something.